# Named key in function not working

Tags: php

I have a piece of PHP code that attempts to add a named `key=>value` pair within a function.  It works fine when it's just written as straight code (character_name and character_color are existing functions in the file that work correctly.  All they do is pull strings from existing data):

```
$name = character_name($character_id);
$color = character_color($character_id);
$array = array("character"=>$name, "color"=>$color);
$characters_array['character']=$array;
```

However, when I try to wrap it within a function and name the key value a variable, it no longer works and generates a null value:

```
function character_array($key,$character_id) {
    $name = character_name($character_id);
    $color = character_color($character_id);
    $array = array("character"=>$name, "color"=>$color);
    $GLOBALS["characters_array"][$key]=$array;
}
```

I know that my issue is with the final line of the function, and I suspect that the two sets of square brackets are the problem, but what I don't know is how to correctly write that final line so that I can add a named `key=>value` pair into the global array. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple options to get this to work but I would avoid relying on globals.

The best way in my opinion is to have the function return the data you expect and then assign that where you want. It is by far the clearest thing to read:

```
function character_array($key,$character_id) {
    $name = character_name($character_id);
    $color = character_color($character_id);
    $array = array("character"=>$name, "color"=>$color);
    return $array;
}

//Assign it to the array by calling the function.
$GLOBALS["characters_array"] = character_array("foo", "bar");
```

The other option is to pass in everthing as parameters. This will implicitly assign the data as needed

```
$GLOBALS["characters_array"]=[];

function character_array($key,$character_id, $characters_array) {
    $name = character_name($character_id);
    $color = character_color($character_id);
    $array = array("character"=>$name, "color"=>$color);
  $characters_array[$key]=$array;
}

character_array("foo", "bar", $GLOBALS["characters_array"]);

//This will still show nothing though
print_r($GLOBALS["characters_array"]);
```

Notice though that the above `print_r` does not show the data still. That is because when passing around array PHP does it by value ie making a copy of it in the function and then destroying that when exiting that functions scope.

In order to have a function take an array and do anything to it you will need to pass by reference. This is simple in the function signature you need to add the `&` infront of the variable.

```
//Notice the & infront of $characters_array
function character_array($key,$character_id, &$characters_array) {
    //code from above
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with by get reference of global variable inside function

```
function character_array($key,$character_id) {
   global $characters_array;
   $name = character_name($character_id);
   $color = character_color($character_id);
   $array = array("character"=>$name, "color"=>$color);
   $characters_array[$key]=$array;
}
```